# Can I check GPU availability prior to starting the training job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I want to start a TrainingJob using [AWS Sagemaker SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). As per documentation of the [Estimator Object](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html) There is a function [fit](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.fit) which will start the training job.

Each user has a limit of the number of GPUs that they can simultaneously run. If I write

```
estimator.fit()
```

It might return a `botocore` exception saying that "Resource Limit is Exceeded".

I was wondering if there's a way to figure out if the resource limit will be exceeded without actually running `estimator.fit()` and trying to catch the exception.

Basically run the code in the following way:

```
if not sagemaker.resources_will_be_exceeded(job_description):
    estimator.fit()
```

Looking at the documentation I could not find such a function, however maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I never encountered such function in AWS in my experience and I didn't find any reference in the documentation. Anyway service quotas are known a priori so maybe you can implement your own logic to check that. You can take a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resourcelimitexceeded-sagemaker/).